# Replacing the firestore database with a json file on a personal server in dart flutter

Tags: json, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm going to replace the firestore database with a json file on a personal server.

Currently, information from Firebase is called with this piece of code

```
static Stream<AnnouncementAggr> streamAnnouncementsAggr() {
    var ref = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('announcementsAggr').doc('announcements').snapshots();
    return ref.map((doc) => AnnouncementAggr.fromJson({...?doc.data(), "id": doc.id}));
  }
```

**How and with what changes in the above code can I get the data from the Jason file on the personal server?**

AnnouncementAggr code:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import '_parsers.dart';

part 'announcement_aggr.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class AnnouncementAggr {
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: '', name: 'id')
  String id;
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: [], name: 'data')
  List<Announcement> data;

  AnnouncementAggr()
      : id = '',
        data = [];

  factory AnnouncementAggr.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AnnouncementAggrFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AnnouncementAggrToJson(this)..remove('id');
}

@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Announcement {
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: '')
  String id;
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: '')
  String image;
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: '')
  String title;
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: '')
  String link;
  @JsonKey(defaultValue: '')
  String body;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: parseToDateTime, toJson: parseToDateTime)
  DateTime? timestampCreated;

  Announcement()
      : id = '',
        image = '',
        title = '',
        link = '',
        body = '',
        timestampCreated = null;

  factory Announcement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AnnouncementFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AnnouncementToJson(this)
    ..remove('id')
    ..remove('timestampCreated');
}
```

I tried a lot with this code and got an error in the source

```
_makeGetRequest() async {
    // make request
    var url = Uri.parse("MY_URL");
    Response response = await http.get(url);

    // sample info available in response
    int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    Map<String, String> headers = response.headers;
    String contentType = headers['content-type'];
    String json = response.body;

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(json)));

  }
```